# How does one show a regular map is finite $ \pi: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1, \quad(x, y) \mapsto x $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $g(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of odd degree and let $X=V\left(y^2-g(x)\right) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. Assume that $k$ has characteristics different from 2 .
How do we show that the regular map
$$
\pi: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1, \quad(x, y) \mapsto x
$$
is finite.

The problem I have is that the definition of finite map I am using is based on the definition given by Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry I: Let $X, Y$ be quasi-projective algebraic sets. A regular map
$$
f: X \rightarrow Y
$$
is finite, if for all $y \in Y$ there is some affine open neighbourhood $V \subset Y$ of $y$, such that $U:=f^{-1}(V)$ is affine and $\left.f\right|_U: U \rightarrow V$ induces a finite map of rings $f^*: k[V] \rightarrow k[U]$, i.e. the pullback map $f^*$ makes $k[U]$ a finitely generated $k[V]$-module.

This doesn't seem like something that is easy to apply. Are there better characterizations of finite maps or do we just have to try and apply this definition?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use the whole space. You are looking at the structure of
$$
k[x, y]/(y^2 - g(x))
$$
as a $k[x]$-module. Show that it is finitely generated. (Hint: a priori it's clear that $\{1, y, y^2, \ldots\}$ generates this $k[x]$-module, but you can eliminate things from that list because...)